# C# Как убрать пространство иконки в ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms, hide

Возле menuitem всегда квадратная пустая иконка. Как ее убрать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DisplayStyle = Text;
BackColor = Menu.BackColor
```